# Projecting Circles of a Sphere on a Mercator Projection

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Recently, I have come across a map showing the coverage of a missile given its radius on a Mercator projection. In a 3-D space, the boundary of the missile would be a circle of a sphere. However, I am curious as to how this is translated onto the 2-D Mercator projection. [Note that the launch is from around North Korea, symbolised by the triangle, with a radius of 8000km.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWIzK.png)

Assuming that the Earth is perfectly spherical, and that it has a radius of $1$, if I have the latitude ($φ$) and longitude ($θ$) of a location, and the range $d$ of the missile, how would I find the formula giving me the 2-D graph upon the Mercator projection (in the form $y=f(x)$)? Currently, I am in the last year of secondary education (I would highly appreciate it if the method did not extend beyond this level too much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some formulas exist that correspond to the curve of a buffer (circle) as seen on Mercator, in the special case of a spherical Earth. They are explained [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1932JRASC..26..161G). They are not quite in the form y = f(x), but they are the easiest that I know of. Note that 3 cases need to be handled, depending on the radius and the latitude of the center. However, I do not know how that relates to your current level of math, it requires a good understanding of trigonometric functions and identities to use them.

Another approach that is used a lot in software is to generate a series of points all around the center with either [spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) or the more accurate [geodesic direct formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem), and then project (calculate X,Y from Lat, Lon) those points on Mercator with [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Derivation_of_the_Mercator_projection) and use them to form and display a polygon.

As you may have noticed, a buffer around a point on Earth, when projected to Mercator, can result in all sorts of shapes that may seem couter-intuitive at first. That is because a map projection distorts reality and distances. Your map reminds me of the famous mapping error in the Independent that showed the range of missiles as simple circles on a Mercator map. As you can see, this mapping error vastly underestimated the distances (left), vs the corrected image to the right.

[image: Error in the Independent]